# no build/script directory in lib/modules for a WSl2 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kernel-module, wsl-2

I built and configured a kernel in WSL2 (wsl-5.4.91, gcc 9.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04 WSL)

While installing **MLNX_OFED** I get the error that there are no files in the **lib/modules//build/scripts.**

**I there an easy way to copy the scripts in there?**

I read this but didn't get far: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594470/wsl-2-does-not-have-lib-modules

---

Here is how I got there:

> home/thilo/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-ubuntu18.04-x86_64# .**/mlnxofedinstall --add-kernel-support**

but I got the following error:

> ERROR: Failed executing "MLNX_OFED_SRC-5.4-1.0.3.0/install.pl --tmpdir
> /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/mlnx_iso.127_logs
> --kernel-only --kernel 5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+ --kernel-sources /lib/modules/5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/build --builddir
> /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/mlnx_iso.127
> --without-dkms --without-debug-symbols --build-only --distro ubuntu18.04" **ERROR: See
> /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/mlnx_iso.127_logs/mlnx_ofed_iso.127.log
> Failed to build MLNX_OFED_LINUX for 5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+**

Opening the **mlnx_ofed_iso.127** file to see for the error

> Logs dir:
> /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/mlnx_iso.127_logs/OFED.326.logs
>
> General log file:
> /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.4.91-MS-new WSL2+/mlnx_iso.127_logs/OFED.326.logs/general.log [32m
>
> Below is the list of OFED packages that you have chosen
>
> (some may have been added by the installer due to package dependencies):
> [0m
> ofed-scripts mlnx-tools mlnx-ofed-kernel-utils
> mlnx-ofed-kernel-modules iser-modules isert-modules srp-modules
> mlnx-nvme-modules kernel-mft-modules knem-modules
>
> Checking SW Requirements...
>
> [31mOne or more required packages for
> installing OFED-internal are missing.[0m
>
> **[31m/lib/modules/5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+/build/scripts is required for
> the Installation.[0m**
>
> [31mAttempting to install the following missing
> packages: python3-distutils dh-python make dh-autoreconf chrpath
> linux-headers-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+ dpatch swig build-essential bzip2
> debhelper graphviz quilt python3 pkg-config gcc[0m
>
> [31mFailed
> command: apt-get install -y python3-distutils dh-python make
> dh-autoreconf chrpath linux-headers-5.4.91-MS-new-WSL2+ dpatch swig
> build-essential bzip2 debhelper graphviz quilt python3 pkg-config
> gcc[0m

Comment: I guess with passthrough you can get Infiniband hardware to run in a Linux VM, but RDMA isn't going to work properly, is it?  You would need some cooperation from the Windows IOMMU.

Answer (score 0):

So the WSL2 is a monolithic kernel, which means no modules are generated as they aren't supported by WSL2 by default. However when compiling yourself, you can compile and install modules by using `sudo make modules_install` once the kernel has finished compiling. In this case, you'll need to add the MLNX_OFED module to the kernel if it's not part of the native kernel and enable within the kernel config. I also recommend bumping your kernel version to the 5.10.x branch of WSL2 that exists now. See https://wsl.dev/wsl2-kernel-zfs/ for example, which covers adding ZFS.